# Does jenkins CI support PHP App Engine applications?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, jenkins

Does jenkins CI support only Java and Python? Or does it support PHP?

In jenkins website I see documents related to Java/Python only.

Comment: I'm currently setting my local Jenkins for my PHP project so, yes, Jenkins supports PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins CI is written in Java so you will need a Java installation to run it. Other than that, it's a general purpose tool that runs arbitrary software on your system. If you want to run PHP tests, you'll have to make sure your PHP is installed on your Jenkins build machines. If you want to deploy to App Engine from Jenkins, you'll have to make sure the App Engine deploy tools are installed on your Jenkins build machine. But both of these things can definitely be done.